# Getting null value when passing json object from jsp to external javascript file

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I'm passing a json object from my jsp file to my js file in the following way:

In the jsp file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/sortGrid.js"></script>
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(orderDetailsList1);
    <input type="hidden" value='<%out.println(jsonArray);%>' id="jsonArray"/>
    out.println(jsonArray);  //----> printing fine, getting all the data
```

In the js.file:

```
var jsonArray = document.getElementById("jsonArray");
    console.log(jsonArray); //-----> getting null here
```

Why am I getting the json data as null in the js file?

Comment: Have you checked the HTML output of the JSP page?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Yes, it's printing the output fine in jsp.